# How to explain parameters written sequentially and separated by commas , correctly and without ambiguity ?. ( a,b,c,... )

Tags: sentence-construction, phrase-request

I am confused of using plural or singular form to explain some parameters listed sequentially and separated by comma. compare:

X,Y, and Z **are** length,  width, and  height **(, respectively)**..

X,Y, and Z **is** length,  width, and  height **(, respectively)**.

Now questions:

1. > Plural or Singular ? Is there any difference?
2. > Is the adverb **respectively** essential to avoid confusion ?

Regards

---

Edition: Adding Context

[image]

Comment: Given that it produces confusion, why not just say, "***X is length, Y is width, and Z is height.***"  No need to think plural/singular, no need to add "respectively"...

Comment: Because, 1) (my tought)its really wordy. 2) (real reason) I have never seen such a sentence in the academic papers.

Comment: 1) It's longer only by a few characters, 2) "Absence of evidence is not evidence of absence", perhaps all those authors like to save a few taps on the keyboard...

Comment: @VictorBazarov Dear, victor how can I post the IEEE journals here ? However, I am going to  put a link so that you can read it.

Comment: What for, Your Eminence?  If you see the pattern and like it, just follow it. Why bother asking here?

Comment: @VictorBazarov Since I hate memorizing and imitating. I want to understand. Is there any problem ?

Comment: @VictorBazarov  As you can see, I have found your suggestion. But it is not very common.

Comment: It does not matter how common it is.  What matters is the ease of understanding.  Even a rare phrase can be easy to understand, and as such can eventually become common as more people start using it.  Tradition is not always the best advisor.

Comment: @VictorBazarov I hope so, but editors are the editors... . I am afraid of them. Perhaps, since I am not good in English, I am not very self-confident.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nouns linked by "and" agree with "are", "is" is not correct.

Normally "respectively" is required to avoid confusion when givigng instructions to solve a problem. Not adding "repsectively" seems to be a question asking people to solve which one is length among x,y,z.